# PyQt5 scrollArea with GridLayout of Image buttons blur/resize when scrolling

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am new to PyQt5 or GUI design in general.
I am trying to make a scrollable grid layout of image buttons. When I try to scroll, the image buttons will resize and blur. Image: [blur scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykt36.png)

Here is my code:

```python
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction,
                            QComboBox, QWidget, QAbstractButton,
                            QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, 
                            QScrollArea, QDockWidget, QLabel,
                            QLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QPixmap, QPainter)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QSize,pyqtSignal, QRect)

class pic_button(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, parent=None):
        super(pic_button, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(pixmap)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(100, 200)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), self.pixmap)

    def pic_change(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(pixmap)

class gui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui_init()

    def ui_init(self):
        self.gallery_widget = QWidget()
        self.gallery_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.gallery_layout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SizeConstraint.SetFixedSize)

        self.buttons = []
        i = 0
        j = 0
        arr = []
        for x in range(100):
            img_path = "index.png"
            button = pic_button(img_path)
            if j > 10:
                i = i + 1
                j = 0
            self.gallery_layout.addWidget(button, i, j)
            self.buttons.append(button)
            j = j + 1

        self.gallery_widget.setLayout(self.gallery_layout)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.gallery_widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

        self.setGeometry(600, 600, 600, 600)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    ui = gui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have been googling for hours trying to find a solution for this. I think I need to go with QGraphicsView and changing my paintEvent for my pic_button(). I want it to be like an image gallery viewing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOUND A SOLUTION**

The paintEvent() when receiving the event.Rect() has the rect's x and y not always at 0, since it is influenced by the scrolling. When QPainter goes to drawPixmap() the blurring occurs.

```python
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.pixmap)
```